# Normal Noetherian rings of dimension at least 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, noetherian

[image]

1. We want to pick $I_g$ to be "maximal" but what is the partial ordering to which it is maximal? For two $f,g \in A' - A$, I don't see how $I_f$ and $I_g$ would be related via subsets.
2. How can we see that $q \subseteq I_{a_2 g}$? $q = I_g = \{a \in A \mid ag \in A\}$ so $a_1 a_2 \in I_g \Rightarrow a_1 a_2 g \in A$ but $a_2 g \notin A$. Let $a$ be such that $ag \in A$. How can we see that $aa_2 g \in A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $I_g$ is maximal with respect to the inclusion of ideals.
2. If $ag\in A$ then $a(a_2g)\in A$ (since $a_2\in A$), so $\mathfrak q\subseteq I_{a_2g}$.

Comment: I see, so we are using $a(a_2g) = a_2 (ag)$? For some reason, I wasn't thinking about commutative rings...